# Given a set of $n$ 2D vectors, find subset of vectors with sum length is the greatest.

Tags: optimization, algorithms, vectors

In this problem we are given set of n 2d vectors and we are asked to find a maximum distance from (0, 0) that we can achieve by adding vectors.

What would be an optimal algorytm for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let your vectors be $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. You want to find
$I\subseteq[\![ 1,n ]\!]$
such that the vector $v=\sum_{i\in I}v_i$ has the maximum norm possible.

Suppose for now that $I$ reaches an optimal vector $v$. Because we can assume without loss of generality that every of the $v_i$ is non-zero, 
thus $\| v\|>0$ and the scalar product of vectors with $v$ is non trivial.
I pretend that:
\begin{align}
  \forall i\in I,\ &\langle v_i,v\rangle >0 \tag{1}\\
  \forall i\in [\![1,n]\!]\setminus I,\ &\langle v_i,v\rangle <0 \tag{2}
\end{align}

Proof:

> First, notice that we indirectly claim that for every vector $v_i$, we must have $\langle v_i,v\rangle\neq 0$. Assume for a contradiction that there is some $v_i$ such that $\langle v_i,v\rangle = 0$. Then we get $\|v+v_i\|^2 = \|v\|^2 +\|v_i\|^2 >\|v\|^2$ which contradicts the assumption that $v$ is optimal.
>
> For $(1)$, let $i\in I$ and assume for a contradiction that $\langle v_i,v\rangle <0$. Let $\hat v=v-v_i$.
>   Then
>   $\|\hat v\|^2=\|v\|^2-2\langle v_i,v\rangle+\|v_i\|^2>\|v\|^2$ and we reach the same contradiction.
>
> (2) stems directly from the two remarks above.

Knowing that, a possible strategy is to go through every lines that separates your $n$ vectors into two "nice" subsets. By "nice", I mean that the line is not parallel to any of the vectors.
One way to do that, is to
get the polar coordinates of your vectors and to sort them by directions (what I mean by that is that you compare the angles $\theta$ modulo $\pi$ rather than $2\pi$). You get at most $n$ distinct directions, any directions in between those correspond to a line that splits your set of vectors "nicely", and thus defines two "candidates" for optimality.

Once you have a line, it splits your $n$ vectors into two sets: one set of vectors "above" the line, the other of vectors "below" the line. Compute the norms of the sums over these sets. Repeat for all directions. You will find the optimal in quadratic time.
(You have $n$ directions, and each time you have to go through the $n$ vectors to get the norm of the "candidates".)